# Django: Getting the most recent distinct objects

Tags: django, django-orm

Supposing I have a `WeatherReport` object with fields `date`, `temperature`, and `city`.

I want to get all the most recent `WeatherReport` objects for each city. I think I would do something like

```
WeatherReport.objects.order_by('-date').distinct('city')
```

But this fails, returning the error

```
ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot the selector (all, filter...) in your request: WeatherReport.objects.all().order_by('-date').distinct('city')

Comment: Could be related to the database backend. In the examples at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct they note that most listed will only work in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Anish is right.  DISTINCT() expressions need to have those fields first in the ordering to perform the grouping necessary to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 8):

This should work. It worked with me when I came across this problem.

```
WeatherReport.objects.order_by('city', '-date').distinct('city')
```

It seems that the `DISTINCT ON` expression(s) must match the leftmost `ORDER BY` expression(s). So by making the column you use in `distinct` as the first column in the `order_by`,  I think it should work.